# YouTube mass downloader renaming files with date published and title

Tags: windows, download-manager, youtube

I'm looking for a Windows software I've already used but can't recall the name.

It was able to automatically download multiple files from a YouTube channel and organising the mp4 files inside a folder with channel name and naming each video file with the date of publishing and title.

Like "Channel Name/2015-12-25 Video Title.mp4"

I'm searching for a software with these features.

Comment: Any luck finding something?